# How can I make a list of lists in R?

Tags: r

I don't know how to make a list of lists in R.
I have several lists, I want to store them in one data structure to make accessing them easier. However, it looks like you cannot use a list of lists in R, so if I get list l1 from another list, say, l2 then I cannot access elements l1. How can I implement it?

**EDIT-** I will show an example of what does not work for me:

```
list1 <- list()
list1[1] = 1
list1[2] = 2
list2 <- list()
list2[1] = 'a'
list2[2] = 'b'
list_all <- list(list1, list2)
a = list_all[1]
a[2]
#[[1]]
#NULL
```

but `a` should be a list!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can easily make lists of lists

```
list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

mylist is now a list that contains two lists.  To access list1 you can use `mylist[[1]]`.  If you want to be able to something like `mylist$list1` then you need to do somethingl like

```
mylist <- list(list1 = list1, list2 = list2)
# Now you can do the following
mylist$list1
```

---

Edit: To reply to your edit.  Just use double bracket indexing

```
a <- list_all[[1]]
a[[1]]
#[1] 1
a[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

Comment: @capoluca To expand on Dason's explanation, `list_all[1]` does not select the first _element_ of `list_all`. For lists, `[` retrieves _sublists_ while `[[` retrieves _elements_.

Comment: If you create a list of duplicate lists like `mylist <- list(list1, list1)`, is `list1` copied or referenced twice?

Comment: What if I am creating a list of lists in a loop and so I do not have the individual sub-lists computed and stored in variables. Rather, I wish to add them to the list of lists one-by-one as I compute them.

Comment: @Leonid It sounds like you should post your own question but is there a reason you aren't using something like `lapply`?

Comment: @Leonid mylist = append(mylist, list(list3))

Answer (score 11):

Using your example::

```
list1 <- list()
list1[1] = 1
list1[2] = 2
list2 <- list()
list2[1] = 'a'
list2[2] = 'b'
list_all <- list(list1, list2)
```

Use '[[' to retrieve an element of a list:

```
b = list_all[[1]]
 b
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

class(b)
[1] "list"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to keep a `list` of `list`s (similar to `python`'s `list.append()`) then this might work:

```
a <- list(1,2,3)
b <- list(4,5,6)
c <- append(list(a), list(b))

> c
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 5

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 3):

The example creates a list of named lists in a loop.

```
  MyList <- list()
  for (aName in c("name1", "name2")){
    MyList[[aName]] <- list(aName)
  }
  MyList[["name1"]]
  MyList[["name2"]]
```

To add another list named "name3" do write:

```
  MyList$name3 <- list(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers pointed out in a more complicated way already, you did *already* create a list of lists! It's just the odd output of R that confuses (everybody?). Try this:

```
> str(list_all)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : chr "b"
```

And the most simple construction would be this:

```
> str(list(list(1, 2), list("a", "b")))
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : chr "b"
```