# R - How to create an arbitrary list of lists

Tags: r, list

I am trying to create a list of lists in R but the interior list are only being stored as temp variables as I go through a loop and when I try to access one of the sub-lists inside of the larger list, I only receive the first element of the sub-list.

I found this answer [R. how make list of lists in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776742/r-how-make-list-of-lists-in-r) but it is not working for me and I think it might be due to the fact that I am not storing each list.

Here is my code:

```
list1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
allLists <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
    allLists[i] = list1
}
newlst = allLists[[3]]
newlst[2]
#[[1]]
#NULL
```

I wold like to be able to access all the lists within allLists but it does not let me. The value for newlst is 1 when I would like it to be the list `(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Do you want `allLists[[i]] <- list1` in the for-loop?

Comment: @jogo yes I think that is what I needed. I am new to R as of last Friday so I am not exactly sure what the double brackets really mean but your suggestion worked and I will look into what the double brackets do. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Answer (score 2):

If we want to create a list of `list`s an option is `replicate`

```
replicate(5, list1, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: My actual application of this will be using different lists and adding them to one big list so I can store them. I only used l`list1` replicated 5x  as a way to simplify my code for the question. But yes that would work if I needed `list1` several times in a big list.